# Obtaining Unique Tokens for Each Request in JMeter Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am working on a performance testing scenario using JMeter, and I need to obtain a unique token for each request within a Thread Group(s). The token is coming from an HTTP request. So for example, if we are sending 100 requests need to obtain 100 unique tokens.

I have an HTTP Request Sampler that retrieves the token.
I have another HTTP Request Sampler that uses the token and sends the request.

My current doubt is how to make sure when each thread is executing the flow, it should always execute the Token HTTP Request Sampler first and get the token.

Can anybody tell me how can I achieve something like this? What's the best practice? Previously I was using Setup Thread Group in Global Level outside of all the Thread Groups and used a single token for all Thread Groups and Requests. But now need a unique token per each request.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

JMeter executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down so it's sufficient to place the request which gets the token above the request which uses the token.

If you plan to run the "token" request only during first iteration of the Thread Group you can put it under the [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)

The approach with setUp Thread Group is also viable, but make sure to use unique properties names, i.e. use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) as the property postfix.

More information: [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So 1 and 3 are some common ways and most used ways and at the same time are those the best practices? Because I have many **Thread Groups** and with all requests I need to send a Unique Token for each, which means I will need to duplicate that Token HTTP Request Sampler inside every Thread Group.

Comment: You can put it under a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and reference it using [Module Controllers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) where required. This is a common way for avoiding [code duplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in JMeter

Comment: Then how can I use the TOKEN if it is inside a Test Fragment? Previously, with setUp Thread Group it was persisting as a PROPERTY. But PROPERTY is Global Scope. And now with a Test Fragment and 1 Unique Token per 1 Request, what is the way to retrieve the token?

Comment: Because previously I was using a HTTP Header Manager as a common headers which was in Global, so with every request it will send the Token (I mean PROP). But how can I do such a thing with this Test Fragment? Basically, we need to extract the token and send it with the Request, mainly 1 unique token per 1 request and another request shouldn't use that same Token.